# Missing listChildren method in php sdk 2.2.1

Tags: php, google-php-sdk

I'm using release version 2.2.1 (latest) of the google php sdk.  I need to get a list of all the files/folders from a specific folder on drive.  From Google's documentation the proper way to do this is [explained here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list).  But when I use their example (passing in the id of the folder where I want to list the children) I get this error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Google_Service_Drive::$children
```

Looks like this method has been removed or am I missing something.  Is there another recommended way?

Side note: wish google would give the php sdk a little more love.

Comment: Please give us *your* code

Comment: does 2.2.1 use v3 of the Drive REST API?  If so, I dont't think REST v3  supports "children".  at least I can't find in the docs: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/